# Is it safe to touch a running 1 hp electric motor?

Tags: motor, ac, electricity, insulation

This question is about touching the housing of a generic AC electric motor like this one:

[image]

...while it's running, without considering any type of insulation, such as wooden floor, rubber gloves or boots, etc. Thanks.

Comment: You can generate a power of 1 hp with totally safe to touch 5 V, or totally deadly 10 kV. The voltage determines how well you need to be isolated so that no significant current can flow through you. For that reason, no answer is generally right.

Comment: If the case of the motor is metal it should be connected to earth ground for safety and regs

Comment: Anything where that SHOULD be ... SHOULD be best measured before touching, or at least not touched in any way that could muscle lock you ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motor shown is has a totally enclosed fan cooled (TEFC) housing. The cooling fan is driven by the motor shaft and is covered by the housing around the motor on the end opposite the driveshaft end. For a motor of that size and type, it would be very unusual for the voltage to exceed 600 volts. The windings are well insulated from the housing. A properly installed motor would have the housing grounded by an equipment grounding conductor. For the motor to be unsafe to touch, it would need to be both improperly installed and not in good condition. The answer would be the same for a large home appliance except that home appliances are not connected to voltages above 240 volts.

Comment: "it would need to be both improperly installed and not in good condition" - are you sure that no design of 1hp motor has (specified and documented!) leakage current (especially if some kind of EMI filter is incorporated in the motor!) large enough to be at least very unpleasant in the case of "motor is fine but improperly installed"?

Comment: If a motor is powered by a VFD, there certainly could be an unpleasant level of leakage current. I would say that installing an EMI filter inside the motor and connecting it to the motor housing would be improper. Two installation errors could certainly create an unsafe situation. An installation error and a sub-standard distribution system could also create an unsafe situation. However, none of these situations are any less safe that the same situation with a home appliance. The OP stated in a comment that the motor is 220 V. If it is above that, it should be considered more dangerous.

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of "let's slap a 1uF capacitor to ground in the motor, that will deal with EMI, the motor case is supposed to be grounded, and the manual clearly states not to operate that motor on a 30mA RCD...."

Comment: I have felt the "tingle" of CM noise leakage in a VFD powered 208V motor on a bench without a proper ground path, it's not just "unpleasant", it outright hurts...

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "touch the stator"? The Stator is a set of coiled wires inside of the frame of the motor. You should not be able to 'touch" anything electrically live without disassembling the motor frame, in which case it cannot be "running". Your question either makes no sense or you don't understand what you are looking at.

If you can see the coils and possibly get a finger through an air flow opening, besides it being exceptionally stupid to stick your finger into a piece of rotating machinery, the coils themselves are insulated, even though they may APPEAR to be bare copper. That however does not mean it is electrically safe. There could be leakage due to age, damage, defect, etc. You don't want to test it by stopping your heart...

Comment: Sorry, I meant the housing -not the stator- of an 220 V (1 hp) electric motor.

Comment: If you do not trust the earth ground connection on an installed motor, test it. If you trust who installed it was competent, then it should be 0V  Grounded case is mandatory, usually with a Green wire.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Of course you have to pay attention to [where that green (or green/yellow) wire goes.](http://gfretwell.com/electrical/portable_generator_ground.jpg)

Comment: that's too funny Spehro